# Is it possible to position all chess pieces on the board such that all pieces defend at least one piece and attack at least one piece?

Tags: chess, puzzles

Is it possible to position all chess pieces on the board such that all pieces defend at least one piece and attack at least one piece?

Comment: When you say "pieces," do you mean *just* the pieces, or the pawns as well?

Comment: I mean the pawns as well. I think doing it that way makes it more interesting and complicated... :P

Comment: This reminds me of a computer problem, How do place X (I forgot the number) queens on the board so they don't "attack" each other?

Comment: @Tom: Perhaps you're thinking of this one? http://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/queens/queens.html

Comment: @El'endia: Exactly.

Comment: @BlueRaja - since when are pawns not pieces?

Comment: @Charles: I'm not sure why, but in chess literature, "pieces" refers to everything but pawns (with "minor-pieces" referring to the bishops and knights).  So for instance, when Nimzovich says *["Control the center with pieces"](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/3363#3363)*, he means don't control it with pawns, as in  traditional theory.  See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_%28chess%29).

Comment: @BlueRaja - interesting, I had never seen anything like that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes**, and it's not particularly hard to do. Here's one solution.

[image]

I found this by placing the pawns first (because they are much more limited in their attack/defence potential), and then adding the pieces one at a time. Using this simple manual approach, it took about 15 minutes to find a solution. As an added constraint, I avoided placing the kings in check.

There are undoubtedly many alternative arrangements that would also work. It would be quite straightforward to write a computer program to search for valid configurations. A simple brute-force [backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) would probably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done "naturally" in a normal chess game though.

The pawns on columns A and H only have 1 square of influence for attacking/defending, since they are on the edge of the board. To move them further into the board, they would have to capture another piece, and if you do, you don't have **all** the pieces on the board anymore.